# DropDown list in JasperReports Server 5.2

Tags: drop-down-menu, jasperserver

I have to create a dropdown list in *JasperReports Server 5.2*. I have to create a report in which, when I select any item from the dropdown list, particular report should be generated.
I am not getting any dropdown tool.

Comment: The *iReport* is just a *GUI* designer for building report's templates

Comment: can u tell me in jasperserver? i have created report in jasperserver, but i want all dates in a dropdown list from which user select and the corresponding data will be displayed

Comment: [Getting Started with JasperReports Server](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-jasperreports-server)

Comment: I had gone through this link as well but couldnt find any solution to my problem. can you please let me know how to create controls like textbox, calender control , dropdown etc in jasperserver reports

Comment: You can read the *5.3.2 Adding Input Controls* topic of *JasperReports Server User Guide*